# Doubts about the "periodicity trick" to compute temperature

Tags: black-holes, qft-in-curved-spacetime, wick-rotation, unruh-effect, thermal-field-theory

The "periodicity trick" is a mysterious way to compute some sort of temperature associated to a Rindler-like spacetime.

Suppose there exist coords $R\in(0,\infty), \eta\in(-\infty,\infty)$ covering a patch of spacetime such that the metric takes the form $$ds^2 = -R^2 d\eta^2+dR^2,\tag{$\star$}$$

where I'm suppressing any orthogonal flat directions. This is the metric of the right Rindler wedge, in Rindler coords. (Note: I've not included any constant factors like the surface gravity, so dimensions might look a bit odd throughout this question).

Defining $\theta=i\eta$ we find the Euclidean metric

$$ds_E^2 =  R^2 d\theta^2 + dR^2. \tag{$\dagger$}$$

The periodicity trick proceeds in three steps:

**(1)** We claim that $\theta$ should be taken to be a periodic coordinate, $\theta \sim \theta+c$ for some constant $c$.

**(2)** To avoid a conical singularity in the metric $(\dagger)$ at $R=0$, we must have $c=2\pi$.

**(3)** We wave our hands and mumble "periodicity in imaginary time = inverse temperature", therefore concluding that the Lorentzian spacetime $(\star)$ has inverse temperature $\beta = 2\pi$.

I have questions about each of these three steps:

**(Q1)** Why should $\theta$ be periodic at all? Why not have $\theta\in (-\infty,\infty)$?

**(Q2)** Why shouldn't there be a conical singularity at $R=0$? Usually something is said about the Einstein equations implying smoothness, but I don't see how the Einstein equations are relevant here.

**(Q3)** *What state are we calculating the temperature of?* Spacetimes do not have a temperature (as far as I understand). Temperature is a property of thermal density matrices. So if this calculation is to make any sense at all, it must refer to a specific state somewhere. (For example, perhaps the relevant density matrix is the one obtained by tracing out the pure vacuum state on a larger spacetime?)

Note: answers can assume that I am confident using Euclidean path integrals to prepare states/find transition amplitudes, and that I am familiar with the KMS condition $\langle \mathcal{O_1}(t_1,\mathbf{x_1})\mathcal{O_2}(t_2,\mathbf{x_2}) \rangle_\beta = \langle \mathcal{O_1}(t_1+i\beta,\mathbf{x_1})\mathcal{O_2}(t_2,\mathbf{x_2}) \rangle_\beta $.

Comment: Given a thermal density matrix you can always find a purifier for it, e.g. the thermofield double. Although I don't see why this is required for it to make sense. Also, surely you agree that the periodicity trick gives the same answer as Hawking's original derivation which didn't use the periodicity trick.

Comment: @ConnorBehan I didn't mean to imply that we need a purifying system for the argument to make sense; just that we surely must be talking about $\textit{some}$ state in order to talk about temperature at all. I've changed the wording in Q3 to make this a bit clearer. And yes, I agree the periodicity trick gives the correct density matrix at $\mathcal{I}^+$ given the field was in the Minkowski vacuum state on $\mathcal{I}^-$. My question is $\textit{why}$ the trick works.

Comment: This is not an answer, but there is a paper by Unruh and Weiss, namely [DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1656](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.29.1656), which does the computation using an Euclidean path integral and makes the process quite clear imo. I don't recall how clear it is in addressing Q2, but I do believe it addresses Q1 and Q3. It might be useful to take a look.

Comment: @NíckolasAlves That paper gives a convincing derivation, but as far as I can tell it doesn't use the "trick" that I refer to in the question (there's no mention of avoiding a conical singularity). I may well be missing a connection, though.

Comment: @nodumbquestions I also do not recall it mentioning the conical singularity (notice I said above that I didn't recall whether it addressed Q2 hahaha). I *think* he bypasses it formulating the issue in a slightly different way to get to the point. It is not an answer to your question (that's why I'm posting as a comment), but i thought it would be useful to mention.

Comment: I think that intuitively the idea behind Q2 is that if you take a circle with a given radius $R$ and you cut a sector between zero angle and your periodicity $c$ modulus $2\pi$ and glue the sides of the sector and you get a cone embedded in 3D, the tip of the cone is sharpened so this is not a singularity in $R=0$ instead there is just no smoothness of the manifold in that point, where Jacobi matrices and higher derivatives are singular at this point.

Answer (score 1):

**Amendment:**

The answer below is not correct. See discussion thread. I am leaving it up in case somebody can point out exactly what is wrong with it or until somebody gives a correct answer.

**Original Answer**

This is an old post, but I was confused by this myself so perhaps this will be of some use to somebody. The periodicity trick is not supposed to give a derivation of anything, it is just supposed to be a trick to obtain the temperature of a thermal state that comes from reducing the density matrix of a state that is smooth across the Rindler horizon. As for why it works, here is one way to think of it:

Take a real scalar field on Minkowski space. Suppose we want to compute the the partition function of the thermal ensemble $e^{-\beta H}$ on a semi-infinite region of Minkowski space, which we can describe with the Rindler metric:

\begin{equation}
    ds^2 = dR^2 - R^2 d\eta^2
\end{equation}

Where  $H$ is the conserved charge associated with Lorentz boosts $H = Q[\partial_\eta]$. We can compute this partition function using a path integral with Euclidean action and periodic boundary conditions:

\begin{equation}
    Z(\beta) = \mathrm{Tr}(e^{-\beta H}) = \int \mathcal{D}\psi \mathcal{D}\chi \delta(\psi - \chi) \int_{\phi(0) = \psi}^{\phi(\beta) = \xi} \mathcal{D}\phi e^{-S_E[\phi]}
\end{equation}

Since $\eta$ is the time coordinate conjugate to $H$, we can evaluate this path integral by integrating over a Euclidean manifold obtained from analytically continuing $\eta$ to $\eta_E = i\eta$. This Euclidean manifold has metric:

\begin{equation}
    ds^2 = dR^2 + R^2 d\eta_E^2
\end{equation}

The periodic boundary conditions of the path integral are enforced by requiring that $\eta_E = \eta_E + \beta$. This turns the metric on the Euclidean manifold into a conical metric which has a conical singularity at $R = 0$. An integral over a manifold with a conical singularity is divergent, so we find that the partition function is ill-defined. This tells us that the state we started with was singular on the Rindler horizon. The only way to avoid this is if the inverse temperature $\beta = 2\pi$ in which case the metric becomes a smooth cylindrical metric. So any regular state (i.e. with regular energy-momentum tensor, two-point functions, etc.) which reduces to a thermal ensemble (with respect to $H = Q[\partial_\eta]$) on the right Rindler wedge must have inverse temperature $\beta = 2\pi$.

Of course, the Minkowski vacuum is regular in the above sense, and it reduces to a thermal ensemble on the right Rindler wedge, so the periodicity trick tells us the temperature of this ensemble. Equally, if you are interested in some other space-time, with a patch that can be described by the Rindler coordinates, then the same argument will apply. As long as you know already that the reduced density matrix of this state will be thermal on the patch described by Rindler coordinates, and that the state is smooth on the Rindler horizon, then the periodicity trick will automatically give you the temperature.

Comment: Are.you saying that $Tr(e^{-\beta H})$ is finite only for $\beta = 2\pi$? This feels wrong since $Tr(e^{-\beta H})$ is a decreasing function of $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, if you include the Rindler horizon $R =0$ in the calculation there should be a delta function contribution coming from the tip of the cone. The calculation can be regularized by excluding the tip (formally taking a cutoff in the geometry at $R = \epsilon > 0$ and then taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$). This will give you something finite that should behave in the way you are expecting. Physically, this regularization is what you would want to do to calculate observables that are relevant for observers who live in the right Rindler wedge and who stay away from the Rindler horizon

Comment: Conceptually, to prepare a state on the full Minkowski space that has a reduced density matrix with modular Hamiltonian $Q[\eta]$, but with inverse "temperature" $\beta \neq 2\pi $ you would need to prepare a state that has discontinuous field configurations across the Rindler horizon. This discontinuity creates high energy density localized at $R = 0$ and if you include this in the calculation of observables you get divergences.

Comment: I don't think your argument is correct. If $tr(e^{-\beta H})$ converges then $tr(e^{-\beta' H})$ also converges for any $\beta' > \beta$. This is just a mathematical fact, true regardless of the operator $H$.

Comment: There is some sense that what you say is correct, but I think in a QFT it can be a bit subtle. Product states in QFT have infinite energies, so you could have the "same" density matrix have either finite or infinite partition function depending on whether it comes from a product state or an entangled state. For example, firstly take the Minkowski vacuum $|0>$ and consider the reduced density matrix on the right Rindler wedge $\rho_R$. Secondly, consider the product state $\rho_L\otimes \rho_R$.

Comment: If you compute the partition function (or any observable) of $\rho_R$ obtained from Minkowksi vacuum  and the $\rho_R$ obtained from the product state, ignoring the contribution from $R=0$ they will both be the same. However, if you include the contribution at $R=0$ the first one will give something finite and the second one will give something infinite, because the product state has high energy density at the Rindler horizon. There is a brief explanation of this in section 3.5 of Harlow's Jerusalem lectures, and you can also look at references therein.

Comment: I don't know what "partition function of a density matrix" means.

Comment: I just mean the trace of the density matrix. I called it a partition function as the density matrix is like a thermal ensemble.

Comment: OK I took a bit longer to think about this and I agree with you that there is a mistake in this argument. Even if the state has high energy density at the Rindler horizon it would not make the trace of an unormalized density matrix diverge, and even if the thermal ensemble on the Rindler wedge has a high energy density on the Rindler horizon there is no reason why this would make the partition function diverge. Thanks for your comments. I will think about this more carefully.